# Multiple Footers in Business unit

Tags: marketing-cloud

We want to know few things about footers :

1) Can we have multiple footers for a Business unit? If yes how we can do that?
2) If create a footer in administration at BU level, then there is a requirement for multiple footers then can we provide multiple footers in case?
3) If we are using different templates having footer with all personalisation string then why it keeps on asking for the physical address.

Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to open a case with support to have that business rule turned off. Right now, it’s looking for the profile information personalisation string, to keep your emails can spam compliant. Once this happens, you can add as many filters as you want with the template. You can also use an ampscript jack to by pass this.

The ampscript to bypass this looks like this:

```
%%[ if 0 == 1 then ]%% %%Member_Busname%% %%Member_Addr%% %%Member_City%% %%Member_State%% %%Member_PostalCode%% %%Member_Country%% %%profile_center_url%% %%[ endif ]%%
```

Comment: The ampscript bypass is a good trick, but be VERY careful as this can leave you open to breaking CAN-SPAM compliance.  You need to always make sure that any time you use this bypass that the address information is definitely inside that email.